# jQuery Image Hover on top of multiple dynamic images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I have a full table of images and just want to always display a small icon on the bottom right of every image on hover.  Any ideas how I do this?  Right now I have this, and it is just showing the hover image in the same spot every time...it needs to show on top of the image that is hovered.  Thanks!

```
.enlargeImage {
background:url(images/xxx) no-repeat;
position:absolute;
width:16px;
height:14px;
z-index:200;
display:none;
}

$('.table_imageThumbs a').mouseover(function(){
            $(this).show('.enlargeImage');
        });


<div class="enlargeImage"></div>

<table width="408" class="table_imageThumbs">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="102" class="td_thumb"><a><image width="75" height="97" class="img_vertThumb"></a></td>
                    <td width="102"><a><image width="75" height="97" class="img_vertThumb"></a></td>
                    <td width="102"><a><image width="75" height="97" class="img_vertThumb"></a></td>
                    <td width="102"><a><image width="75" height="97" class="img_vertThumb"></a></td>
                  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I needed to use an each loop and qtip to get what I wanted...thanks for help:

```
$('.table_imageThumbs img').each(function(){
          $(this).qtip({
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery to dynamically append a `.enlargeImage` element after the `a` tag that´s being hovered over and give all table cells a `position: relative` and `.enlargeImage` a `right: 0; bottom: 0`. You´d have to remove the `div` again on `mouseOut` (when the hover ends).

However, I have read somewhere here that there are possible problems with absolute positioning inside table cells (can´t find it right now...) so it might not work as expected.

Some untested example code:

```
el = $("<div>")
     .addClass("enlargeImage");

$('.table_imageThumbs a').hover(
  function() {
    el.appendTo(this);
  },
  function() {
    el.remove();
  });
```

Comment: 'el = $('.enlargeImage');

  $('.table_imageThumbs a').hover(
    function() {
   el.appendTo(this).show();
    },
    function() {
   el.remove();
  });'

Comment: This works but it shows the '.enlargeImage' icon in the same spot every time...what about using 'position()' someway to get it's position relative to the div and then place it? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @webwrks You have not copied my example completely; I am adding a new element and you are selecting an existing element (you need to remove that `div` from your code). You also need the `css` modifications from the first part of my answer.

Comment: @jeroen, I tried the code 'el = $("<div>")
       .addClass("enlargeImage");

  $('.table_imageThumbs a').hover(
    function() {
   el.appendTo(this).show();
    },
    function() {
   el.remove();
  });'

Comment: and I got the same results...the div was removed also...the only modification I used was the 'show()' function because the 'enlargeImage' class is hidden...now I'm stuck...

Comment: @webwrks Do you have an example page online?

Answer (score 0):

OK, two things:

1. If you want to show the correct `.enlargeImage`, you'll need to do something like:

   `$(this).siblings('.enlargeImage').show(); //depends on whether .enlargeImage is a sibling`
2. You'll need to make the parent element containing the image and the icon `position: relative` so the `position: absolute` of `.enlargeImage` is relative to the correct parent.

<strike>If you need more help than that then you'll need to show your HTML structure, preferably using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).</strike>

**Edit:** I see you've got your HTML up now. You'll need a `.enlargeImage` in each `<td>` if you want it to appear relative to the hovered image.

Comment: ok, thanks for help, I'm trying both now, but can't give the '<td'> the '.enlargeImage' class because it will hide the image completely...I'll keep you posted.