# Positioning and overlaying image on another image

Tags: html, css, image

See how the tiny Facebook icon is positioned in the lower right-hand corner over another image?

[image]

How can I do that using a combo of HTML/CSS/Rails/Prototype!?  An example would be great.  Perhaps in jsfiddle.net.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I position one image on top of another in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's a simple example using divs instead of images: http://jsfiddle.net/sqJtr/

Basically, you put both of your images in the same container. Give the container a position that isn't static (in my example, relative). Then give the overlay image `position: absolute` and position it however you want using `bottom` and `right`.

Comment: best answer. this has been the easiest explanation to this problem I've seen, after many months of google searching

Answer (score 32):

You can use css to solve the problem.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
.imtip {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blaly.png" />
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/favicon.ico" class="imtip" />
</div>
```

Basically, I've done more or less what ZDYN said, just that you need to include a `display: inline` in the container otherwise the container `div` spans the whole width.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. This is done using 2 images.

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="http://i.ehow.com/images/a06/dv/5g/buy-car-repair-manuals-online-200X200.jpg" />
    <div class="inner"><img src="http://www.airporthybridrentals.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/car-rental-sign.gif" /></div>
</div>

.parent{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
}

.inner{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/WPWzq/

Comment: thanks, the "z-index" was really necessary, without it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

[See my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949063/jquery-image-hover-on-top-of-multiple-dynamic-images/4949187#4949187).

The difference with your situation is that you don´t need any javascript if you don´t want to, you can just add divs to the html and position them absolutely on top of the photos.

I think I would personally add the divs using javascript anyway so that they don´t clutter the html.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```css
html, body, .wrapper { height: 100%; }
.wrapper { position: relative; }
.top { height: 15%; background: #222; }
.mid { height: 70%; background: #CCC; }
.bot { height: 15%; background: #777; }
.container { 
    position: absolute;
    background: #FFF; 
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 80%;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -40%;
    clear: both;
}
.container > div {
    float: left;
    width: 42%;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 1%;
}
.container > div:first-child {
    background: #EEE;
    float: left;
    width: 54%;
}
.container > p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100px;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
    width: 50%;
    height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="mid">
        <div class="container">
            <p>Some Text Here</p>
            <div>IMAGE HERE</div>
            <div>DESCRIPTION HERE</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bot"></div>
</div>
```

*Collected from stackoverflow.*