# Superimpose Images with PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I am searching for a way to overlay an image on an existing image.

e.g:

[image: img1] + [image: img2]

I have found a great example over here: [PNG overlay using one single Image element.](http://www.tjkdesign.com/articles/png_overlay_with_no_extra_markup.asp)
but I have **two** problems with these.

**First** of all, I don't want the dimensions to be equal to each other. e.g (215*215 on 215*215). This is because my users would have the ability to choose where they want to put their image. (Top, left, bottom, top-right) so 8 directions.

The **second** problem is that in that example, only 2 images are allowed to overlay. My users (again) will have the ability to put multiple images on top of it.

I have a little knowledge of Javascript and PHP, so it would be great if you guys (and girls) could help me out.

Sincerely,

Comment: What is the relevance of Javascript and PHP? Have you decided that you need to use these technologies? Either? Both? Is that a requirement, or did you just assume that the solution will involve one or both of them?

Comment: Also you've not provided any context at all. Is this to go on a website? Do you need to do this dynamically to arbitrary images, or just once to a single image? You say "their image" as if "[your] users" are uploading these images, but give no specifics as to what your system is supposed to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Positioning and overlaying image on another image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130374/positioning-and-overlaying-image-on-another-image)

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry for this less information. I'm creating an app on android that streams snapshots to my webserver (a website). It works with a POST Method (PHP) that receives the correct details. Javascript is needed to reload my images every 750 milliseconds. Now, *my* users (on the android platform) has the ability to select an image in their SD card directory and it's send to the webserver. An example is like on tv. Showing the name when you are live from a person, or showing an image or something. It could be multiple images on 1 single image. I assumed the solution is both of them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this using [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library. There is function to "merge" images called [`imagecopymerge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php).

Here is a very simple example how to merge images:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$bg = imagecreatefromjpeg('background.jpg');
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');

imagecopymerge($bg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($bg), imagesy($bg), 75);

imagejpeg($bg, null, 100);
?>
```

Comment: Ok, great. So this takes my existing image, merge a new image into it (for example bottom left) and make them into one image? Nice! also, does this have to be a jpeg, is there also a possibility for PNG/GIF

Comment: @XverhelstX You can create PNG or GIF image by changing Header content type and using `image*` function where `*` is extension. Links: Creating [PNG](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) | [GIF](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php)