# Add some logo to all images in folder

Tags: php

Can I add a logo to all my images which are in the `Images` folder?
If yes, how can I place the logo at the bottom left of the image?

On this picture you can see `cinepicks.com` in the middle of the picture. I want a logo on the bottom left of a picture and I want to do this only with PHP.

[image]

Can it be done with the imagepng() function?

Comment: what does that mean...? Can you be more clear..

Comment: Question is not clear, do you want a thumbnail image of every image in folder.

Comment: Yes sure it can be done. But we need to know if you want that nobody can view the image without the logo in any way. Because then it is more complex.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

Answer (score 1):

1. Loop over each image file in a directory.
2. Overlay your logo on each one.

You should be able to overlay an image according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6547828/39321). Placing it in the lower left corner is just a matter of calculating the coordinates correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I use a class called [phpthumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/demo/phpThumb.demo.demo.php)  for that. It's as easy as calling a url and you can do everything with image manipulation.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.