# create a image dynamically from two or more overlay images

Tags: php

i have two images with overlays and text overlays on those images,text is at certain angle on images and one image will be at certain angle on another image. i want to create one new image dynamically from both these images and text. How can i do that in php.

Comment: So no jsfiddle? Code? Anything?

Comment: Use the PHP image functions, all the details are in the manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) also see previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547784/overlay-image-over-image